# Add a space in column header while binding ObservableCollection to a Grid

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to add a space in my column header when I am binding my ObservableCollection to a Grid in MVVM way. Here is my code..

```
public class Site
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Description("Short Code")]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public string ShortCode { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<Site> GetSampleData()
    {
        var sites = new ObservableCollection<Site>();

        sites.Add(new Site { Name = "New Delhi", Description = "New Delhi Railway Station", ShortCode = "NDLS"});
        sites.Add(new Site { Name = "Mumbai", Description = "Mumbai Railway Station", ShortCode = "MUM"});

        return sites;
    }
}
```

// Here is my View Model Class

```
public class SiteViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Site> SitesDataCollection { get; set; }

    public SiteViewModel()
    {
         SitesDataCollection = Site.GetSampleData();
    }
 }
```

// This is the View Class

```
public partial class SiteView : UserControl
{
    public Sites()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new SiteViewModel();
    }
}
```

My XAML is

```
<Grid>
   <DockPanel>
     <DataGrid Name="SiteGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SitesDataCollection}">
     </DataGrid>
   </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Basically in my Grid, for the third column , the header is ShortCode, I want to display "Short Code", How can I do that.

I tried adding

```
[Description("Short Code")] and 
[Bindable(true)]
```

but didn't got the desired result.

Comment: @Muds, I have added the XAML as well in the question, It just uses ItemsSource binding to SitesDataCollection.

Comment: Any reason why not to set AutoGenerateColumns to false and explicitly defines the datagrid layout?

Answer (score 1):

In the AutoGeneratingColumn event handler of the DataGrid, access the DataGridColumn properties by referencing the DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs.Column property. Use this to edit the column header.

```
private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.Header = Regex.Replace(e.Column.Header.ToString(), "(\\B[A-Z])", " $1");
}
```

This will add spaces into your property names where there are upper case letters.